# Do I need Xcode 4.5.2 to be able to build iPad mini compatible apps?

Tags: xcode, ipad-mini

I already know that if an app is iPad 1/2 compatible, it will work fine on an iPad Mini since they have the same resolution.
The other day I updated my Xcode from 4.5 to 4.5.2 and one of the update description lines mentioned something like:

> This version allows iPad Mini and iPad 4th Generation compatibility

Let's assume that all my view's frames are well prepared to run on any screen, will the apps work on iPad Mini if I compile them with Xcode 4.5 instead of 4.5.2?

Thank you, Alex.

Comment: That's most likely referring to the ability to install and application and debug on those devices from within Xcode. Older versions should still build binaries compatible with those devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. Seeing as all the iPad apps built before Xcode 4.5.2 was out run, yes, of course your apps will run as well.